# My computer is changing text "a la" to "à la"

Tags: windows-10, autocomplete, phraseexpress

I am using Windows 10 aniversary edition, and every time I type the Spanish words "a la" it is changing to the French "à la".

My main language is set to Spanish and the region is set up to Spain.

Also happens in Microsoft Word, Google Chrome, Firefox, notepad,  etc etc.

Any clue what's wrong?

[image]

Comment: You can turn off auto-correct altogether using [these instructions](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/25843-spell-checking-turn-off-windows-10-a.html). You can also access and modify the auto-correct list from within Office, but I can't find this list for general input.

Comment: I turn off autocorrect and reboot, still with the same problem

Comment: You should tag this Windows 10 and remove FF and MS Word tags since the issue is not application specific.

Answer (score 0):

I found it! the problem is with PhraseExpress is a windows program I dont know why when is open is changing text.

Thanks for your help.